# SocketIO manual installation for iOS app swift 4 xcode 9

Tags: ios, github, socket.io, swift4, xcode9

I am having difficulty installing SocketIO for my Swift 4/Xcode 9 app.  I have tried Swift Package Manager and Carthage and both did not work.  Separate threads for those issues.  I do not want to use Cocoapods.

Is there a way to manually install the libraries?  I can drag and drop the Source files successfully however I don't know how to add the SocketIO and Starscream frameworks from the Git downloaded files.  I can figure out how to link the binaries and that stuff myself, just want to know where I can physically extract the two frameworks from in the downloaded file.

Comment: I am successfully integrating SocketIO+Starscream with Carthage, can you explain your issue?

Answer (score 0):

Did you check in your project folder, the Carthage folder then Build folder then iOS folder and same with the Checkout folder?